# Running convert several times for one file

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I wish to run the following four operations on each of a large number of files in a directory. Is there a more efficient (faster) way of doing this? Where me.png is one of the files.

```
composite -compose change-mask background.png me.png me.png

convert me.png -background blue -flatten me.png

convert me.png -transparent blue me.png

convert me.png -quality 95 me.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Use convert in place of composite in ImageMagick and then you can chain all your commands.

```
convert me.png background.png -compose change-mask -composite -compose over -background blue -flatten -transparent blue -quality 95 me.png
```

See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#changemask and https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/

Also note that -quality for PNG is not the same as that for JPG. It is not in the range 0 to 100 as for JPG. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality